# how to access a disposed object in a time-tick event?

Tags: c#, .net

OK, simply put i have a time ticker and after the end of the time tick event i dispose the code inside...however when the timeticker goes again...it cannot access the code within? So why a disposed object cannot be recreated? What do i have to do so each time a timetick event passes the object is used as it has to be and not simply overlooked?? 10x

Comment: "dispose the code inside" ? what you mean by this? Please give an example!

Comment: hi: timertickeven(whatever...) { object thiss = new object(); object.dispose(); } // so next time the time tickerevent passes...the thiss object will not be accessed i guess //

Comment: well...I can't be 100% sure :)...but so it seems. I will try again, it might be because i am way too sleepy now and doing mistakes...but have checked twice. thanks though.

Comment: You cannot access a disposed object. If you throw something away, you can't get it back. It's gone forever. Can you post your code and explain what you're trying to do? It's likely someone can tell you how to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

according to your comments, I assume the code

```
timertickeven(whatever...) { 
    DisposableObject thiss = new DisposableObject(); 
    DisposableObject.Dispose(); 
}
```

is creating an DisposableObject (renamed by me, since object itself does not implement IDisposable), which implements the IDisposable interface. Every time the timer event is fired, such an object is created and afterwards disposed. Since the object is recreated every time, there is no connection to the object which were disposed at the last time, the event handler was executed. The solution therefore is, to get some sleep and watch the situation again tomorrow - with a fresh mind.

Besides: rethink about, if it would be possible to somehow pool those disposable objects. In general IDisposable is for resource consuming or very large objects. Having to recreate them frequently may deminish your execution performance.

Comment: On a side note, I use IDisposable for any objects that need to clean up things up (such as event handlers) before they go away, regardless of their size or resource consumption. Other than that, good answer.